# MongoDB - mongosh script - validation messages

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongo-shell

I am running MongoDB (v 6.0.4) in docker. I have created a collection with a validation schema via a mongo script ( script file - test.js run with bellow command, the file is linked via volumes)

```
mongosh --username username--password password --authenticationDatabase admin ./test.js
```

test.js content:

```
db.createCollection("faculties", {
  validator: {
    $jsonSchema: {
      bsonType: "object",
      required: ["name", "shortcut"],
      properties: {
        name: {
          bsonType: "string",
          minLength: 0,
          description: "Faculty name"
        },
        shortcut: {
          bsonType: "string",
          minLength: 0,
          description: "Faculty name shorcut"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

When I try inserting valid documents into the collection, the validation works. When I add invalid ones the validation also works (documents are not being added, throws error). The issue that I am facing is that there should be additional info logged when an error occurrs (according to [this](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/mongodb/mongodb-5-0-schema-validation/) ). This works after I do what is [written here](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/what-is-the-status-on-improved-json-schema-error-messages/164710) ->
running the mongo shell, running the bellow command for my desired database, restarting afterwards

```
db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: “5.0” } )
```

Afterwards when I try inserting invalid documents in the mongo shell via

```
db.faculties.insertOne({})
```

the correct error containing additional information about the validation failure is logged

This is what the error should look like

```
MongoServerError: Document failed validation
Additional information: {
  failingDocumentId: ObjectId("6457f574543ac2df89f1254e"),
  details: {
    operatorName: '$jsonSchema',
    schemaRulesNotSatisfied: [
      {
        operatorName: 'required',
        specifiedAs: { required: [ 'name', 'shortcut' ] },
        missingProperties: [ 'name', 'shortcut' ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Error that I am getting:

```
MongoServerError: Document failed validation
```

So validation throwing errors works for the mongo shell(after using the db.adminCommand command), however when I try to insert the same document via a mongo script, the additional info is not thrown. How can I enable the same feature for mongo scripts?

Comment: You need to switch compatibility to 5.0 if you have 6.0.x build. Try installing a latest version of 6.0.x or 5.0.x and try again.

Comment: Have a look at [Check the logs for the invalid document](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/schema-validation/handle-invalid-documents/#check-the-logs-for-the-invalid-document.)

Comment: @Gowtham Yes I have already done that.... what worked in the end was just wrapping the insert in the script file with a try catch

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by wrapping the insert with a **try catch**:

```
try {
  const facultyInsert = db.faculties.insertOne({});
  console.log(facultyInsert);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

Comment: First of all, congrats to you, that you've managed to solve your problem. But could you please elaborate a bit more and maybe even provide a working minimal example?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).